# restore database user login error

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to restore a database (SQL SERVER 2008) from a backup in a different server. The problem I have is with the login, as the user is included in the backup but the login is not.

So I try to create a new login in the server but it doesnt seem to work.

anyone knows a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would have been useful if you posted the actual error message and the steps taken to produce the error.

Anyway, I think what you need to do is delete the user from the restored database.  Then you will be able set up the user & corresponding Server login from scratch.

**EDIT:**

If the user owns a schema in the database you won't be able to delete the user.  [There is Microsoft article on how to transfer SQL Logins.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992)

Comment: ok, I managed to remove the user by changing the schema. So I added a new login and user but I still get the same error: Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'xx'.

Comment: @user441365 - Check out this link here for further details on this error.  What is the state? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366351.aspx

Comment: ok I know what the problem was - sql server was set as windows auth only doh!

Comment: @user441365 - Ok, glad it is sorted.  You should probably start accepting answers if they have solved your problem.

Answer (score 15):

That's a very common problem after a restore.  A user (database specific) and a login (server wide) both have a SID.  The problem is probably that the login you created has a different SID from the login on the production database.    You can check the login and user SID like:

```
select UserSid from sysusers where name = 'UserName'
select LoginSid from master.dbo.syslogins where name = 'UserName'
```

Here's a script we run after every backup to repair the login - database link:

```
declare user_cursor cursor forward_only read_only for
    SELECT  distinct u.name
    FROM    sysusers u
    JOIN    master.dbo.syslogins l ON u.name = l.name
    WHERE   u.issqluser <> 0
declare @user sysname;

open user_cursor
fetch next from user_cursor into @user;

while @@fetch_status = 0 
    begin
    if @user <> 'dbo'
        begin
        print '' 
        print 'Updating user "' + @user + '"'
        exec sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', @user 
        end
    fetch next from user_cursor into @user
    end;

close user_cursor
deallocate user_cursor
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! This script saves me hours of wasted time...

Answer (score 13):

Im not 100% sure of the cause of your error but this script helps me when restoring a database from another server, assuming the login and user already exists in the target server:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login UPDATE_ONE, '[username]', '[loginname]'
```

(Substitute [username] with your database username and [loginname] with the server login)

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't comment on the post above - but it worked, the only ammend I had to make was to LINE 4 where I specified the default collate on the field.

```
JOIN    master.dbo.syslogins l ON u.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = l.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```